# iOS - Add custom UIView in the iCarousel

Tags: ios, icarousel

I am trying to add Custom UIViews ( Graphs drawn using Core Plot ) as the elements in iCarousel, but I dont see the Graphs being drawn. Here is my header file :

```
@interface MTViewController : UIViewController <iCarouselDataSource, iCarouselDelegate,    

CPTBarPlotDataSource, CPTBarPlotDelegate>
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet iCarousel *aCarousel;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *label;
@property (nonatomic) BOOL wrap;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet CPTGraphHostingView *graphView;

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *data;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *animals;

@property (nonatomic, retain) CPTXYGraph *graph;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *graphs;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *descriptions;

@end
```

Implementation file is :

```
    - (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {

        //set up carousel data
        wrap = NO;

        self.graphs = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects: self.graphView,nil];
    }

    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    aCarousel.type = iCarouselTypeCoverFlow2;
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [self setACarousel:nil];
    [self setLabel:nil];
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft || interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight);
}

#pragma - mark iCarousel Delegate

- (NSUInteger)numberOfItemsInCarousel:(iCarousel *)carousel 
{
    return [self.graphs count];
}

- (NSUInteger)numberOfVisibleItemsInCarousel:(iCarousel *)carousel
{
    // limit the number of item views loaded concurrently (for performance)
    return 1;
}

- (CPTGraphHostingView*)carousel:(iCarousel *)carousel viewForItemAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index reusingView:(CPTGraphHostingView *)view
{
    // create a numbered view
//    view = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[animals objectAtIndex:index]]];
//    return view;

    CGSize size = self.graphView.frame.size;
    float width = size.width;
    CPTGraphHostingView *currentGraph ;
    for (int i = 0; i < self.graphs.count; i++) {
        CGRect frame;
        frame.origin.x = width * i;
        frame.origin.y = 0;
        frame.size = size;

        currentGraph = [graphs objectAtIndex:i];
        currentGraph.frame = frame;
        [self generateBarPlot:frame];
    }
    return currentGraph;
}

- (NSUInteger)numberOfPlaceholdersInCarousel:(iCarousel *)carousel
{
    return 1;
}

- (CGFloat)carouselItemWidth:(iCarousel *)carousel
{
    // usually this should be slightly wider than the item views
    return 240;
}

- (BOOL)carouselShouldWrap:(iCarousel *)carousel
{
    return self.wrap;
}

- (void)carouselDidScroll:(iCarousel *)carousel
{
    //[label setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [descriptions objectAtIndex:carousel.currentItemIndex]]];
    [label setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Testing"]];
}
```

.... followed by methods to generate graph

Any help will be deeply appreciated.

Thanks for reading.

Comment: I have tried changing the protocol method in the iCarousel.h file to be CPTGraphHostingView, but havent got it working.

Comment: Have you checked the size of the frame?

Comment: Also, appears to be weird.  It looks like the graphView is part of the loaded view, but then you are trying to use that view in the carousel.  This seems weird.  Where does the original graphView come from and have you tried verifying that it is displaying correctly separately?

Comment: The original graphView gets displayed correctly. I added two graphViews in the ScrollView and thats working perfect.

Comment: I can post more code if you would like to take a look.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by casting the Custom View to UIView.

Comment: you did something else. casting doesnt change the type of an object.. e.g. you can CAST an apple into a strawberry -> but that doesnt MAKE it so.

Comment: What I meant was the iCarousel takes UIView or any subclass of it hence I was able to put the Core Plot graphs there.